# How to set id and name of select control present inside <td> of a HTML table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've following HTML code for table and select control:

```
<table id="blacklistgrid_1"  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr id="jumbo">
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Products</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Pack Of</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Quantity</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Volume</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Unit</th>
      <th style="vertical-align:middle">Rebate Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="apnd-test">
    <tr id="reb1_1">
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <select name="" id="" class="form-control prod_list">
            <option value='1'>Alabama</option>
            <option value='2'>Alaska</option>
            <option value='3'>Arizona</option>
            <option value='4'>Arkansas</option>
            <option value='5'>California</option>
           </select>
         </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Now I want to set the name and id of select control from above HTML code to following values:

```
name="product_id_1[1]"
id="product_id_1_1"
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.attr()` to set attributes id and name for select.try this

```
 $('td select').attr('name','product_id_1[1]');
 $('td select').attr('id','product_id_1_1');
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2WFt/)**

**Update:** To target first select element:

```
 $('td select:eq(0)').attr('id','product_id_1_1');
```

Comment: How could I do that if there is another td in different row of a same table containing select control in it?

Comment: @PHPLover - it will apply all td

Comment: in that case you can target the first select element using `:eq` selector. Like this: `$('td select:eq(0)').attr('id','product_id_1_1');`

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to be specific and that is the only select on the page, `$('select').attr('name','product_id_1[1]').attr('id','product_id_1_1');` will suffice.

If you need to be more specific:

```
$('table#blacklistgrid_1 tbody.apnd-test div.btn-group')
  .attr('name','product_id_1[1]')
  .attr('id','product_id_1_1');
```

should be good.

the `name` and `id` properties can be set using `.attr()`. Other than that it just depends how specific you want to be when finding the select element.